# How to measure time spent accessing file data over network-attached storage?

Tags: linux, benchmark, nas

For a program running on a (Linux) server in a network-attached storage (NAS) environment, how can I measure the amount of time spent transferring data between the server and the network?

The `time` command

```
> /usr/bin/time md5sum file_348m
738709b181b52ddfcef3413997f91462  file_348m
0.65user 0.07system 0:00.73elapsed 99%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1524maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+80minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

I believe measures the time spent transferring data between the server's (local) disk and memory (pagefaults), but how can I measure the time transferring data from the network?

Comment: You probably (with a modern kernel) want something from https://github.com/iovisor/bcc

Comment: If you know the port/host it's communicating with, you might find some results using `tcpdump`, recording the packets to a file and then analyzing it.